# What is the max size of NSData can insert in SQlite?

Tags: ios, sqlite, nsdata

I need to know what is the max size of `NSData` that can be inserted in one row of an `SQLite` database => a max size of a column as opposed to the max size of a whole `SQLite` database.

Comment: i need to know for just one row  Anbu-karthik, not the  max size of file data or the all data

Comment: IMO it is a new question - a maximum column size as opposed to maximum database size. The answer is - per default 1,000,000,000 bytes, SQLite can be recompiled to support 2,147,483,647 bytes. You can find it in  https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html.

Answer (score 0):

A maximum column size as opposed to maximum database size per default 1,000,000,000 bytes, SQLite can be recompiled to support 2,147,483,647 bytes. You can find it in [Limits in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)